# GenericTreeModel with PyGObject Introspection Gtk+ 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject, treemodel

I'm trying to write my own Gtk+3-TreeModel based on GenericTreeModel in Python3, but I this error:

> AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'GenericTreeModel'

Has GenericTreeModel been renamed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any reference to GenericTreeModel in PyGObject nor in Gtk, but I think what you are looking for is just TreeModel:

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeModel.html

TreeModel is the interface, is implemented by ListStore, TreeModelFilter, TreeModelSort and TreeStore.

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk
>>> dir(Gtk.TreeModel)
['__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__',
 '__format__', '__gdoc__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gtype__', '__hash__', 
 '__info__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__module__', '__new__', '__nonzero__',
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', 
 '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_convert_row', '_convert_value', 
 '_getiter', 'filter_new', 'foreach', 'get', 'get_column_type', 'get_flags', 'get_iter',
 'get_iter_first', 'get_iter_from_string', 'get_n_columns', 'get_path', 
 'get_string_from_iter', 'get_value', 'iter_children', 'iter_has_child', 
 'iter_n_children', 'iter_next', 'iter_nth_child', 'iter_parent', 'iter_previous', 
 'ref_node', 'row_changed', 'row_deleted', 'row_has_child_toggled', 'row_inserted', 
 'set_row', 'sort_new_with_model', 'unref_node']
```

EDIT:

Found [what you are looking for](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-pygtkgenerictreemodel.html) in old PyGtk API, sadly, this was a PyGtk-only creation. With the introspection stuff you just get only what Gtk directly provides, so you will have to deal with TreeModel directly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @JanHolthuis: could you report back on your progress? I'm trying to port an GenericTreeModel-based app to pygobject without success yet.

Answer (score 4):

PyGObject recently gained GenericTreeModel support through [pygtkcompat](https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/pygtkcompat/generictreemodel.py).

This is new in [3.7.90](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pygobject/3.7/pygobject-3.7.90.news) with a fix in [3.7.91](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pygobject/3.7/pygobject-3.7.91.news)

So now you should be able to migrate GenericTreeModels by using the compatibility module, at least as a start.

Answer (score 3):

So I’ve been coping with this for a while. Here are my results:

- As Havok already said: the `GenericTreeModel` does not exist anymore and one has to use the normal `gtk.TreeModel` interface and override the appropriate methods (naming them `do_…`):

  ```
  class TreeModel(GObject.GObject, gtk.TreeModel):
     def do_get_iter(self, iter, path):
         …
         iter.user_data = whatever()
         return True
  ```
- Inheriting from ListStore or TreeStore does not work when using custom iters etc.
- The repository with call information is broken (see [launchpad:gtk3#1024492](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1024492)) so that the do_get_iter method is called without the iter argument, so you cannot set custom data on it.
  To fix it change the direction for the `iter` argument in `/usr/share/gir-1.0/Gtk-3.0.gir` from `"out"` to `"in"` and run:

  ```
  g-ir-compiler --output=/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/Gtk-3.0.typelib /usr/share/gir-1.0/Gtk-3.0.gir
  ```